# Eclipse Fails To Launch Complaining of Incompatible Java VM

Tags: java, eclipse

I get the following error when trying to launch Eclipse, which I recently tried to install.

"Version 1.6.0_65 of the JVM is not suitable for this product.  Version 1.7 or greater is required."

I'm running Mountain Lion.

I have the most recent 1.8 installed from Oracle, and this is the install I would like Eclipse to be using.  The following image shows the info from the Java Control Panel including the version number and the install path.

[image: Oracle Installed JavaVM version and path]

Here's is the info on the Apple installed Java VM which is the one Eclipse is currently trying to use.

```
~> which java
/usr/bin/java
~> java -version
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-462, mixed mode)
~> ls -l /usr/bin/java
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  74 Oct 16  2013 /usr/bin/java -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java
```

Comment: Which version of eclipse did you try

Comment: eclipse-standard-luna-SR2-macosx-cocoa-x86_64.tar.gz which I believe is version 4.4.2

Comment: Which Java 1.8 did you install? and what does `java -version` show

Comment: `~> which java
/usr/bin/java
~> java -version
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-462, mixed mode)
~> `  All of which refers, I believe, to the Apple installed JVM.

Comment: I've added an image to the question showing the info on the Oracle Java VM installation pulled from the Java Control Panel.  It specifies version 1.8.0_31 and is installed in `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java`.  I imagine this is the install I should be using for Eclipse.

Comment: Setting JAVA_HOME is my .bashrc made no difference.  Nor could I figure out how to use the -vm flag in Eclipse.ini.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comments you have  the Java 8 JRE which is only a web plugin you need to install the Java 8 JDK

Changing things in ~/.bashrc does not effect the environment of apps launched in the GUI

Comment: Installing the Java 8 JDK solved the problem.  Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

watch this video to solve your problem incompatible jvm/jdk 1.8/1.7 requires 11 or higher version.
https://youtu.be/UysE4KN-HGY

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. We expect answers to be self contained, since if your link goes down, your answer will be useless. Paraphrasing the source and including any relevant information in the answer will ensure it stays relevant